# Compare two arrays for specific data

Tags: php, arrays

I have a little problem. I have  to compare arrays like this :

```
array(2) {
 [0]=>
  array(4) {
["persons"]=>
int(1)
["date"]=>
string(21) "2018-10-01 2018-11-14"
["type"]=>
string(7) "for one"
["sun"]=>
string(3) "yes"
 }
[1]=>
 array(4) {
["persons"]=>
int(2)
["date"]=>
string(21) "2018-10-01 2018-10-14"
["type"]=>
string(7) "for two"
["sun"]=>
string(3) "yes"
}}
```

And now I have options, which picked user for example :

```
array(2) {
["type"]=>
string(7) "for two"
["sun"]=>
string(3) "yes"
```

}

And now I have problem to compare these two arrays. I need records from first array only which are difference and match with the search variables from array two. I need result like this in this case :

```
array(1) {

[0]=>
array(2) {
["persons"]=>
int(2)
["date"]=>
string(21) "2018-10-01 2018-10-14"
}}
```

I tryed array_diff and array_intersect but this is not result what I need. I tryed also in foreach loop but I can't fix to get my target. Is there some ready php function to get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have this in the most generic way you can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) and [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

consider the following example:

```
$a = array("a" => "aaa", "b" => "bbb", "c" => "ddd");
$b = array("a" => "aaa", "b" => "bbb", "c" => "ccc");
$arr = array($a,$b); // this is your base array

$find = array("b" => "bbb", "c" => "ccc"); // this is as your options (what you want to find)
```

Now you can do:

```
$barr = array_filter($arr, function($elem) use ($find) {
        return count(array_intersect($find, $elem)) == count($find);
}); // $barr contains only the sub-arrays that contains the option you wanted


$carr = array_map(function($elem) use ($find) {
        return array_diff($elem, $find);
},$barr); // $carr contain only the field that are not in the option array
```

Now the `$carr` is your desire output